# JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of.. out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, jackson

I know there are a few questions on stackoverflow regarding this problem. But I have have been spending hours trying to resolve this error without any success.

I am using the mysql database to store the values.

I keep on getting the error message from the
com.example.springboot.Recipe file.

This is springboot recipe file

```
package com.example.springboot;
import com.example.springboot.Recipe;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import  javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class

public class Recipe {

    public Recipe(){

    }

    public Recipe(Integer id, String name, String description, String type, Integer preptime, Integer cooktime, String content, Integer difficulty){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.type = type;
        this.preptime = preptimee;
        this.cooktime = cooktime;
        this.content = content;
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;


    private String name;


    private String description;


    private String type;


    private Integer preptime;


    private Integer cooktime;


    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String content;

    private Integer difficulty;






    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setTitle(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Integer getDifficulty() {
        return difficulty;
    }

    public void setDifficulty(Integer difficulty) {
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
    }

    public Integer getCookingtime() {
        return cooktime;
    }

    public void setCookingtimeime(Integer cooktime) {
        this.cooktime = cooktime;
    }

    public Integer getPreparationtime() {
        return preptime;
    }

    public void setPreparationtime(Integer preptime) {
        this.preptime = preptime;
    }
}

Main Controller:
@PutMapping("/recipes/edit/{id}")
    void updateRecipe2(@PathVariable int id, @RequestBody Recipe recipe ) {

        Recipe recipe_ = recipeRepository.findById(id).get();
        recipe_.setTitle(recipe.getTitle());


        System.out.println("sss " + recipe.getname());



        System.out.println("change");
        recipeRepository.save(recipe_);
    }
```

service.ts:

```
updateRecipe2 (id: number, recipe: any): Observable<any > {
    const url = `${this.usersUrl}/edit/${id}`;
  return this.http.put(url ,recipe);
}
```

where the updateRecipe2 gets called:

```
 save(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('name');
     this.recipeService.updateRecipe2(id, this.recipes)
       .subscribe(() => this.gotoUserList());

   }
```

as soon as the user clicks save this functions saves the changes made.
I hope the code snippets that I provided are enough to help solve the problem.
Thank you in advance.

I am building a rest api with spring boot and I am using angularjs as it's frontend. I am pretty new to web-development.

Answer (score 2):

You are sending a list of recipes to an api endpoint that expects a single recipe object.

Your options are:

- Send only one recipe object at a time, for example:

  ```
  this.recipeService.updateRecipe2(id, this.recipes[0])
  ```
- OR: create a new API endpoint to accept a list of recipes, to edit them in "batch"

  ```
  @PutMapping("/recipes/edit")
  void updateRecipes(@RequestBody List<Recipe> recipe ) {
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I changed the recipeservice as you described but I dont understand the second point. How should I modify the api endpoint to accept a list of recipes?

Comment: I also got another error `threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present] with root cause`

Comment: Given that this API endpoint has ID as a URL path parameter, it's not easy to modify it, you would have to create a new API endpoint for this usage. The new endpoint would accept a list of recipes and do the "edit" operation for each recipe. As for the new error, it sounds like no recipe exists with the ID you are sending, which makes  `recipeRepository.findById(id).get()` fail.

Comment: Thank you. I will try and modify the code. However I don't understand the error. when I check in the database if the values are present they are there.

Comment: That's always possible

Comment: I have a question to `OR: create a new API endpoint to accept a list of recipes, to edit them in "batch"`and  the putmapping example you provided.  Should this putmapping be in the first puttmapping function ? Don't understand what you mean with edit in batch.

Comment: You have an API endpoint that updates ("edits") the data for a single recipe in the database. You are sending multiple recipes to it. The suggestion is to make a new API endpoint that accepts a list of recipes, and updates all them in one go ("in batch").

Comment: But my idea is just to update the name of the recipe instead of the whole recipe. Maybe I didn't explain myself probably I'm sorry. In my website I have a different section where someone can change the name of the recipe instead of opening the whole edit endpoint. So in the recipes overview I want to be able to edit the name of the recipe.

Answer (score 0):

my Example:

Use:
@PostMapping

Code:

```
public void setTransacciones(List<Transacciones> transacciones) {
    this.transacciones = transacciones;
}
```

CodeBean:

```
public class Transacciones {
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    private String text; 
}
```

Post(raw):

```
{
     "transacciones" : [ {"text" : "1"}, {"text" : "2"} ]
}
```

Result:

```
{
   "transacciones": [
       {
        "transaccionId": 2,
        "text": "1"
       },
       {
        "transaccionId": 3,
        "text": "2"
       }
    ]
}
```

BINGO!!